# Perl Dancer: Reading the file from browser

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, dancer

Using `Perl Dancer`, I am  planning to read a file from the browser, do some processing on the data and send back the new data to user. But, i am not able to read the data from the file handle.

Also, could you please let me know how can we send the data back to user?

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS Registration Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css"/>
</head>
<body>  
    <form method="POST" class="register">
       <p> Please select a file to upload:
           <BR> <INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="tfile">
       </p>         
    </form>
</body>
```

Testing_app.pm:

```
package Testing_App;
use Dancer ':syntax';
our $VERSION = '0.1';
get '/' => sub {
    template 'index.tt';
};
post '/' => sub {    
    my $tp = params->{fname};
    my $tv = params->{vname};
    my $tf = params->{tfile};
    open(LOCAL, ">tp.lst") or die $!; 
    open(FN, "<$tf") or die $!; 

    while (<$tf>) {
        print LOCAL $_; 
    }
    template 'first.tt', { su => $tp, sv => $tv, sw => $tf };
};
true;
```

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`Dancer::Request::Upload`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Request::Upload) has an example of how to handle file uploads:

```html
# somewhere in your view:
<form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="filename">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```perl
# and then in your application handler:
post '/upload' => sub {
  my $file = request->upload('filename');
  $file->copy_to($upload_dir);  # or whatever you need
};
```

Note that the example uses `/upload` for the route that actually posts the file data. (Creating two `/` routes that only differ in their request method would be confusing.)

Also note that the `name` attribute of your form element must match the value you pass to `request->upload()` (in this case, `filename`).

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot Thank you for your reply. Looks like the above code uploads the file content to server. But i am planning to read the contents from the file handle, do some chnages and return back the file. Initially i tried before posting in stack overflow. where, In a scalar context $file gives us the file name. But when i am planning to use it as a file handle i am not able to do so. Can you please let me know if i missed out some thing.

Comment: @Praneeth Please read the documentation I linked. In the example code, the file is written to a temporary file. You can get a read-only filehandle using the [`filehandle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Request::Upload#file_handle) method. For security reasons, though, it would probably be better to move the file out of the world-readable temporary directory using the `copy_to` method before manipulating it.

Comment: @ThisSuitlsBlackNot Hey I am able to figure this out. Thanks a lot for your help!